# Static or relative path for PHP class files?

Tags: php

I typically include my PHP class files like so:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

include_once("$root/classes/my.class.php");
```

Is this recommended or should I just use a relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `realpath()` incurs some overhead because it calculates the canonical path, inspecting each part of the folder structure leading up to your source file.

Another approach is by using `__DIR__`:

```
include __DIR__ . '/classes/my.class.php';
```

For class loading whereby each file comprises only one class, you should look into [autoloading](http://php.net/autoload) them.

Comment: In my case the files have several classes

Answer (score 2):

You should load classes using an autoloader like this:

http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/

Edit: A summary. You shouldn't load your classes manually, but should instead configure your application to load them automatically.

See this for a simple implementation (simple is good - follow this code)

https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md